# Japan cheapest way to travel? Is carpool/ride share common in Japan?

Tags: budget, japan, tips-and-tricks, backpacking

I will be travelling to Japan for 2 weeks and found train tickets little bit expensive. Usually i travel like a backpacker and always travel with a budget. I will be staying different cities in Japan and looking for a cheapest possible option to move within different cities. In the past especially affluent countries, i have used extensively buses and sometimes shared rides which proved really feasible. I need to know the following few questions:

1 Is ride share/ carpool common in Japan?

2 Are bus tickets really the cheapest option to travel in Japan or should I rent a motorbike?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information as to you expected journey legs? Tokyo to Osaka is a highly travelled transportation corridor and has any number of ways of getting between the two (the cheapest being off-peak overnight buises at anywhere from ￥1500 to ￥3500. Sapporo to Kagoshima in one trip however is a bit more difficult.

Comment: @ the wandering coder I would be looking tokyo ,nagano,toyama, takayama,Nagoya,Osaka,hakone to tokyo

Comment: That seems like a nice round trip. You may find you won't be able to use night buses between the middle of your trip, but they will certainly be cheaper For the Tokyo-Nagano, Nagoya-Osaka and Osaka Tokyo legs. Otherwise consider local buses or trains.

Comment: @ the wandering coder  good suggestion

Comment: Generally speaking, the cheapest options are also the slowest, but you want to visit a lot of places in little time. That's going to be a problem.

Comment: I am tempted to vote to close this question as too broad, as the number of conceivable travel methods seems too large, and their cost not always straightforward to evaluate and compare. For starters, it would help greatly to be more precise about what travel methods are acceptable.

Comment: @fkraiem vote to close? Seems like an interesting topic, isn't it

Comment: By "bike" do you mean bicycle, or something motorized like motorcycle, moped, etc?

Comment: @ stannius I mean rent a bike ?

Comment: @AliAwan will that bike have a motor? Or be powered by your own legs?

Comment: @ stannius motorbike/motorcycle for rent

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The **cheapest** way to travel in Japan is to **hitchhike**. Getting out of major cities is difficult, but once you're on the road, it's generally amazingly easy to get rides. Some knowledge of Japanese helps, but is not mandatory.

Further reading: http://hitchwiki.org/en/Japan

Ride sharing is not common, because driving is not the budget option in Japan if you're paying for it: road tolls are *extremely* high. If you hitchhike, most of your rides will be people traveling for work.

Comment: it's cool that you can hitch in Japan!  would it be typical to contribute towards the enormous freeway tolls?

Comment: @ jptokal hitch make sense so far, never tried though

Comment: @JoeBlow No, they're paying them anyway, a hitchhiker doesn't cost anything extra.

Comment: @JoeBlow the tolls are so high that it is usually way cheaper to take a train than drive alone; only with three people in a car you might get even. Thus those who drive alone are either really rich (and this won't need/care about your contribution), or they're driving for business (and will thus be reimbursed by the company).

Comment: fascinating @GeorgeY. thanks. i've never driven in japan.

Comment: @GeorgeY. I'm by no means rich and I take the toll roads at least once a month (albeit the Tohoku ones are free for certain sections). Depending on the time of day and if you are a foreigner or not, can give you various discounts on your toll.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder thanks for the information about discounts. Are they available to tourists, and how much Japanese one needs to speak to assess them?

Comment: @GeorgeY. Yes. None at all. You mean something like this? http://www.go-etc.jp/english/expressway/index.html

Comment: Thank you, amazingly useful piece of information! Would you mind creating another question and answering it yourself, so this knowledge could be easily found later?

Comment: @GeorgeY. The tolls have come down in recent years and there is almost always a parallel alternative route that locals take. Of course, you better know the roads or have a GPS if you're taking them. For shorter distances, assuming it's not rush hour, the alternative routes are almost as fast as the expressways, as the expressways speed limit is still quite low.

Comment: I personally only had trouble getting out of Tokyo, not the other cities. That's because Tokyo has a special elevated expressway whose rest areas can't be accessed by any rear entrance. You can only get there by car or by locked staff entrances and the staff won't let you in. If you are a diehard hitchhiker you can hitch up an onramp onto this system to one of the service areas and hitch from there. Took me quite a few hours to do though,

Comment: The other hard part is when your route changes expressway more than once in a shortish distance. For this you want a sign with a destination about 50km away on the expressway you want to be on. The name of an SA or PA is good if there is one. Sign in Japanese is best. Just drawing it can get attention and even a ride.

Comment: You can offer to contribute to tolls but you shouldn't insist hard if they say no as there could be loss of "face".

Comment: @ hippietrail every one says tolls are very expensive, how much an average toll cost in japan?

Comment: @AliAwan: I don't know but it could be a good new question to ask. It will vary by kind of vehicle but I got the impression all expressways were run by one company. If you ask be sure to ask average per mile or km and say what kind of vehicle.

Comment: Tolls are about Y25/km, plus an entry fee of around Y500. They're run a bit like JR: regionally split, but all basically government-owned and operated to the same standards.

Comment: @ jpatokal thats really expensive, they charge acoording to mileage plus entrance fee

Comment: @AliAwan: *Really* expensive! One time I noticed the toll price or counted the money the driver was handing over and it was equivalent to about $100!

Comment: @ hippietrail vow thats too much, i should stick to other options besides car and motorbikes

Answer (score 11):

One of the very cheapest ways to travel is the [Willer Express Japan Bus Pass](http://willerexpress.com/st/3/en/pc/buspass/), which costs as little as ¥2100 per travel day for unlimited travel.

Comment: Wow, I have never noticed that any company had a special deal that was also open to residents in Japan.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Yeah, that's because those express buses are usually used by Japanese. Relative to the train, the bus is quite cheap... and many buses travel through the night, so things like taking the overnight bus to Disneyland from Osaka to Tokyo is popular among students.

Comment: These buses are fine. I had immense frustration booking them back in 2008. If their booking system has not improved make sure you thoroughly understand how it works as early as you can to avoid frustration.

Comment: @Armstrongest I used to use the Osaka > Tokyo and return every 2 weeks for about a year and the company never used to offer this (if they did, they never thought to mention it).

Comment: @hippietrail It seems to have improved markedly since then (as has the busses themselves). They have an equivalent to business class seats now and it doesn't cost that much more.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder: I thought the buses were very nice before. Clean comfortable perfectly maintained. But super boring. Nobody talks to anybody else and some even have three rows of individual seats instead of two rows or double seats. I seem to recall a conductor coming and closing all the window curtains too. So the things I didn't like were more cultural quirks than the actual buses. And of course the weirdness with getting a ticket (-:

Comment: Oh they were nice before, but buses now have to compete with LCC's for fares (of which LCC's are usually comparable if not cheaper in price) now so they have to keep upping their game. I found nobody really talks to anyone else on any form of transport here (except for me). The window curtains of overnight busses are usually closed by the person in the seat however I have seen the conductor come and close the ones with unoccupied seats. Tickets are now online / can be bought from convenience stores so it seems markedly easier. Some companies even have the ticket sites in English.

Answer (score 6):

Most people find the JR Pass to be the most affordable and comfortable way to visit multiple cities.

If you're super cheap, then overnight discount intercity buses will save you both transportation and lodging. Google "Tokyo Osaka night bus" or some variation to find examples.

Hitchhiking is illegal in Japan. Intercity ride sharing is not common as highway tolls are very very high so it's usually cheaper to take the train or bus. You could still check in with your gaijin house, hostel, or online bulletin board.

Many people have toured Japan by bicycle so that's also an option.

Comment: There ***IS*** hitchhiking in Japan... And what is a "gaijin house"?

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Cheap, short-term rental apartments targeted at foreigners. And yes, hitchhiking in Japan is entirely possible, I crossed the country from Hiroshima to Hokkaido that way.

Comment: @jpatokal I just took exception to the word gaijin - as I do most of the time. It is literally like saying foreign people house with a negative connotation. What is the problem with saying "short-term rental apartments"? Just a niggle I have.

Comment: @RoboKaren Hitchhiking in Japan is certain ***NOT*** illegal... Where are you getting this from? It is illegal to stop a car or walk on an expressway. It is also illegal to hitchhike near intersections and busy bus stops. Otherwise it is perfectly legal.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Because unlike normal short-term rental apartments ("weekly mansion"), these are explicitly targeted at foreigners.

Comment: @jpatokal Then "short-term rental apartments aimed at foreign visitors" would be better IMO. (I assume they aren't targeted at residents?)

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder They don't actually call themselves gaijin houses, but that's the ubiquitous term just the same.  And they are aimed at residents, not visitors, because regular apartments in Japan have high up-front fees, long lease periods and require local guarantors.

Comment: @jpatokal I see. Does that mean they won't apply to this question (as OP does not appear to be a resident of Japan)?

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Residency is not required, but you probably wouldn't stay in one for less than a few weeks.  And yes, we're well off-topic here.

Comment: I never heard them called anything other than "gaijin hausu". Apparently Japanese can't stay at them. I was under the impression they are share houses which is probably considered a foreign concept in Japan hence the term. Not dorm rooms but shared bathrooms, kitchen, etc. Interestingly I later stayed with Japanese friends in Sapporo in a very new concept share house with both Japanese and one expat family living there. It was a great place.

Answer (score 6):

1) Ridesharing / Carpooling is not common in Japan yet but a small community called "Noritomosan" is working on it (available in english).  The platform allows to find travel friends in Japan, connecting drivers with empty seats to people travelling the same way. If you are a solo travel, you can make plans and look for buddies to come with you (by train, bus are also available) and share the cost of your trip. You can have a look here -> [www.noritomosan.com](https://www.noritomosan.com)

By the way they also have a forum, so maybe it worth asking them directly since they are specialized in "cheapest" way to travel lol.

2) As said before, the cheapest way is to hitchhike. So the cheapest way is to travel by car ;). Rent a Bike ? You mean a bicycle ?

Comment: @ rent a motorbike mean, good feedback about noritomoson

Comment: Are you affiliated with Noritomosan? If so, please mention it in your answer, otherwise, just ignore this.

Comment: Japan also has Uber. I have never used it so I can't vouch for it, but it definitely exists.

Comment: @ JS Lavertu, I'm not directly affiliated but I know the founder and already discussed with him a bit.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder, Uber exists in Japan but only in Tokyo (and they still struggling to expand). A friend of mine tried it and told me that it was the same price as the regular taxi, so no really need to use it.

Comment: @AliAwan, I don't really know the motorbike location system in Japan but as far as I know, since you will not share the cost of gasoline etc.. Given that the toll fees are dreadfully expensive in Japan, it might not be the right idea :(.

Comment: Generally you can get anywhere in Japan on smaller roads and avoid the tolls, but often the routes are so circuitous you'd never find them without satnav, and can be very tiny. I think it would be a wonderful way to travel around Japan but almost impossible if you have limited time.

Answer (score 4):

### Buy the JR Rail PASS

Honestly, you want to go a lot of places in weeks, ~$450 USD (¥46,390) is what a **JR Rail** pass costs for 14 days. It will cost you at least $40 (¥4000 on sale) round-trip just to get to Tokyo and back from Narita Airport, so that drops your cost down to $400.

You want to go to Tokyo, Nagano, Toyama, Takayama, Nagoya, Osaka, Hakone back to Tokyo in **TWO** weeks?  You're going to be on the move for 2 weeks, not staying in one place for more than a couple of days and that makes you a perfect candidate for a 14-day pass.

It's also good for any JR local rail transit, which will help in Tokyo as well if you want to visit Yokohama etc.

Remember, you're travelling **at LEAST** 6 segments. I doubt you'll have time to hitchhike to all those places and if you do, you'll have to be more flexible with your accommodations which may end up costing you more. Sure, cheap buses are available, but given the number of destinations you have planned, the train is a much saner option.

> In short, taking the train may SEEM expensive, but I am willing to bet that trying to visit that many places in that short period of time... The JR Rail pass will end up being the **best** for your needs.

### Are Japanese trains REALLY that expensive?

Japanese trains **seem** expensive because they don't run them like an airline or like European train systems, which charge an arm and a leg for last-minute travel, have complicated ticket classes each with their own rules and offer deep discounts to attract people to book far in advance.

For the most part, Japanese trains are run like a commuter rail system. The price doesn't fluctuate that much, is set at a consistent price, and is extremely flexible, which is why the JR rail pass is perfect for your needs. If you like a place and want to skip the next place, you can feel free to do so without worrying about getting your money back for a bus trip.

Besides, how can you go to Japan and NOT experience what is arguably one of the key defining aspects of modern Japanese culture, the bullet train?

Comment: your answer makes lot of sense

Comment: I never felt any desire to ride a bullet train \-:

Answer (score 3):

Japan buses would be really cheap, especially if you travel at night

Comment: Care to expand a bit more on that ?

Comment: Booking buses can be a real pain though. Very arcane rules. When I used buses in 2008 Willer Express was the cheapest. Buses were nice but you couldn't buy a ticket on the bus or from their office - I tried both! You had to book online, and bookings closed at 4pm the day before! After missing the 4pm deadline twice because the English interface was very poor I ended up trying hitchhiking for the first time. Also tourist information desks know everything about trains and accommodation but very little about buses. It's like nobody expects foreigners to travel by long distance bus in Japan?

Answer (score 3):

Trains certainly are expensive if you buy them on a per-journey basis, but did you evaluate the cost of a JR Rail Pass? If you're travelling a lot it's superb value for money.

Bear in mind that you **must** purchase the JR pass before travelling to Japan; it's too late to get it after leaving your home country.

Comment: Cannot we buy train tickets inside train? Can I buy jr pass a day before travel?

Comment: On some trains you can buy tickets on board, but the question was about the cheapest way to travel. For the JR pass, yes you can go to a travel agent and they can write it out on the spot. Its not the actual pass but a voucher, which must be exchanged at a station in Japan.

Comment: @AliAwan For the most part, you buy train tickets at a machine at the station. Many stations will have automated fare gates.

Answer (score 3):

I live in Tokyo and have been working as a marketing supervisor at B mobile for the past 2 years. Because of my job, I regularly visit Nagoya and Osaka by car.
I have been reading answers about hitchhiking in Japan, so I decided to post an answer here.

Normally, I make the drive at least two times a month and I have never come across any hitchhikers. I have never seen anybody asking for a ride while I drive.

Also, it is not a custom in Japan where people ask for free ride. Although the Japanese people are really friendly, they still might find it strange to see somebody waving their hand in the middle of the road asking for free rides.

So, I think hitchhiking is not feasible in Japan, and it is best for you is go for JR pass or bus tickets

Comment: I've personally hitchhiked from Nagoya or Fukuoka or Shimonoseki to Yamagata and back at least three times and from Naha to Soya Misaki and back to Tokyo once (except for the three ferries). I've also never seen another hitchhiker on any of my trips except for my friend who hitched with me from Sakurajima to Tokyo. So it's not common and it's not customary but despite that it's very easy. I found out about bit by discovering [this web page](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Japan) after Googling for "Japan hitchhiking" out of frustration trying to book a long distance bus ticket from Nagoya in 2008.

Comment: @ hachiro araki maybe you never came across with any hitchhiker in Japan, but seems like travelers have managed to moved across quite comfortably

Comment: @ hippietrail good feedback , the web page you just posted says it is illegal to pick anybody on motorways in Japan

Comment: Yes, it is illegal to be on the actual roadway of motorways, to walk past the tollgates, etc. But it is legal to hitchhike at the Service Areas & Parking Areas along them. All of them except on the elevated sections in Tokyo have employee entrances at the rear and only about 1% are locked. Use Google maps etc to find routes from local train stations to those rear gates. [Hokkaido is an exception for some reason.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27159/) But there it's easy to use the major non-toll roads instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Carpooling is recently raising in Japan**

The biggest carpooling app is currently [Notteco](https://notteco.jp/). It is only in japanese but you can find for instance Tokyo-Osaka rides for less than 5,000 yens which is almost 3x cheaper than the train.

I'm currently working on a [carpool app](https://www.instagram.com/carpool.japan/) specialized for foreigners in Japan. Please check out if you're interested or if you have any suggestions ! :)